# Remove past events from Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization

I sync my Google calendar with Outlook.

I have recurring daily entires in my Outlook calendar which I would like to remove from Google calendar (and Outlook if necessary) when they are in the past.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 2022-03-25: Link below is dead.

[Here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=2ecc73b630453b70&hl=en) is the active thread for this problem over at google support forums. There are some workarounds in that thread that might help you.

Comment: This link is dead. Can you provide update to this answer?

Answer (score 2):

In Google Calendar, the recurring events will be splitted if you modify one of them.

So this is the trick:

1. Find the latest event occurence you want to remove.
2. Edit the subsequent event.
3. Modify the event in some manner (like editing the note, the time or something else), then save. This will split the events as old (unmodified) and new (modified).
4. Remove the previus old event, then select "remove all events".

Done, this will remove all old recurring events preserving the new ones.

Comment: Maybe this will work if I own the event, but in my case, it's a meeting event that I don't own.  Tried this, but it still removed all events (including my modified and subsequent ones).

Answer (score 1):

I'm passing along a good answer from Neil@GCalToolkit.

The easiest way to do this is to go back to the very first occurrence of the event, change the date to the new start date for the series, and when prompted, select "This and following events". Please note that this can't be undone, and you'll lose any data in the deleted occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

No supported way of deleting multiple events in Google Calendar manually or automatically but if you get Outlook to do it then sync to Google it has the same effect.